# How to display Text editor values

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="staff_add" class="form-horizontal" action="trmser.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">   
 <textarea class="form-control input-sm" id="txtEditor" name="details" placeholder="Details">
        <?php //echo $value['details'];?>
        </textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#txtEditor").Editor();
            });
        </script>
```

On **trmser.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST['details'];?>
```

On form submit text editor values not display
Help me Please.

Comment: Note that the newline and whitespace between `<textarea>` and `<?= ?>` will also be displayed on some/all browsers, namely Google Chrome and more.

Comment: Where are the form tags or post method? And do you feel that by not posting the db code is not relevant? Either way, check for errors and the console.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using [Linecontrol](https://github.com/suyati/line-control/)?
You need to add the document.submit part to read the data from the editor and paste it in the textarea. See below:

```
<head>
    <!-- your other scripts like jquery & bootstrap -->
    <script src="editor.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtEditor").Editor();
        });

        $(document).submit(function(){
            $("#txtEditor").val($("#txtEditor").Editor("getText"));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
   <form action="myscript.php" method="post">
        <textarea class="form-control input-sm" id="txtEditor" name="details" placeholder="Details">
        </textarea>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php echo $value['details'];?>
</body>
```

To fill in some text from your application you may use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtEditor").Editor();
  $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", <?php echo $value['details'];?>);
});
```

Comment: now I got curious too :) I updated the answer - let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks its work, But an another problem is Update time fetched data not displayed in text area

Comment: the please upvote mark it as answered :) - you may set a text using `$("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "foo")`

Comment: I do this but here is some html tags

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/suyati/line-control/issues/34) - is that the same issue you are facing?